# How to force iPad to initiate wifi connection?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, uiwebview, wifi

After restarting my iPad it does not automatically connect to wifi. If I open Safari or Pandora or something else then it will connect to wifi. If I open the app I'm developing (which uses the network, e.g. by loading a web page in a UIWebView on the main screen) it doesn't connect to wifi. How do I force the iPad to make a wifi connection like it does with other apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use the property in the info.plist - Application uses Wi-fi.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try the setting UIRequiresPersistentWiFi to true. If there is a different key to set true I couldn't find the exact name.